# RSpec - how to test module in the module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, module, rspec, rspec2

I got module nested in a module

Something like that:

```
module Utilities
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module InstanceMethods
    def fix_text(str, params = {})
      str = Iconv.conv('UTF8', 'LATIN1', str)
      str.gsub!(/\\u([0-9a-z]{4})/) { |s| [$1.to_i(16)].pack("U") }
      str.force_encoding("UTF-8")
      str = strip_html(str) unless params[:no_strip_html]
      MojiBake::Mapper.new.recover str
    end

    def strip_html(str)
      Hpricot(str, :xhtml => true).to_plain_text
    end
  end
end
```

I didnt found on a internet information how to test module in the module.

Please write some pseudo-code for this spec (order of describe and module blocks, how to test if module extend other module etc).

Comment: There is no additionnal constraint when you test a module. Specing/stubbing foolows the usual rules. I can't understand what you expect as an answer

Comment: Actually I'm newbie in RSpec. Can you write some pseudo-code how to test that module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example:

```
require 'spec_helper'

class Foo
  include Utilities
end

describe Utilities do
  it 'should pass' do
    foo = Foo.new
    foo.strip_text(arg).should == expected
  end
end
```

You need to change `arg` and `expected` variables